# ObservedObject return nil even if a value is set in first view Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, option-type, observedobject

I have a Class "ActualCourse"

```
class ActualCourse : ObservableObject {
    @Published var id : UUID?
    @Published var CourseName : String = ""
    
}
```

And two Structs "Settings" and "Course"

```
struct Settings: View {
    @State private var action : Int? = 0
    @ObservedObject var objCourse = ActualCourse()
    @State var courseId : UUID = UUID()
    @State var list : [Course] = [] // list is not empty, I didn't show it to you to make the code lighter
    
    init() {
        objCourse.id = UUID()
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
    NavigationLink(destination: Course(), tag: 1, selection: $action){}
         List {
 let count = list.count
 ForEach(0 ..< count, id: \.self){ index in
           HStack {
Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                                        .font(.title)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                        objCourse.id = list[index].id
                                        objCourse.nomCourse = list[index].nomCourse
                                        print(objCourse.id!) // Id Appear when I click !
                                        self.action = 1
                                        }
```

But when I navigate to Course view, objCourse.id return nil

```
struct Settings: View {
@ObservedObject var objCourse = CourseActuelle()

....

.onAppear(){
            print(self.objCourse.id!) // RETURN nil
            
        }
```

What am I doing wrong ? I have to give a random UUID at the beginning because I can't find how to do in another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CourseActuelle` you're creating in the second view is independent of the one you're creating in the first view of which you're initializing the id value. If you want them to be the same you could use `@EnvironmentObject` in the second view and inject it in the first view or pass it in some other way.

Comment: Thank you, environementObject and obsservedObject are not clear for me... I'll learn more about it !